# react-router redux how can i update state on load of page for authentication

Tags: react-router, redux

I am using https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit as a starter kit and trying to introduce authentication into the starter app.

I have authentication working, it sets `state.auth` on login success, I then have an `onEnter` on my protected routes which calls `isAuthenticated()` to check if the user is authenticated.

This is where i get lost and I am not sure how to check both the `state.auth.user` and the `localStorage.token` to make sure things are set.

The way i see it, i need to account for two cases

1. the user logged in, but then refreshed the page. This means the token is still in localStorage but state is wiped, so I'd need to reload the state by decoding the token and reinjecting it into `state.auth.user`
2. the user isn't logged in, redirect them to the route `/auth/login` (this part i have working).

My problem is using the starter kit i do not know how to **properly** get to state/store within my routes file so i can check for that `state.auth.user` property.. or if thats even the right way to do it (maybe i should be using an action instead)?

**redux/modules/auth.js**

```
import { createAction, handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import { pushPath } from 'redux-simple-router'
// ------------------------------------
// Constants
// ------------------------------------
export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'LOGIN_REQUEST';
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS';
export const LOGIN_FAILURE = 'LOGIN_FAILURE';
export const STORE_USER = 'STORE_USER';
export const IS_AUTHENTICATED = 'IS_AUTHENTICATED';

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  token: ''
};

// ------------------------------------
// Actions
// ------------------------------------
export const requestLogin = createAction(LOGIN_REQUEST, (payload) => payload);
export const receiveLogin = createAction(LOGIN_SUCCESS, (payload) => payload);
export const invalidLogin = createAction(LOGIN_FAILURE, (payload) => payload);

export const isAuthenticated = () => {
  return !!getToken();
};

const getToken = () => {
  return localStorage.token;
};

const _decodeToken = (token) => {
  return window.atob(token.split('.')[1]);
};

const storeToken = (token) => {
  localStorage.token = token;
};

export const doLogin = (identity, password) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(requestLogin({ identity, password }));
    // mock backend call
    setTimeout(function () {
      var token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6ImlzdHJhdG9yIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBhenN1cHJhcy5jb20iLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDE1LTEyLTMwVDIxOjMyOjIxLjM1NloiLCJ1cGRhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDE1LTEyLTMwVDIxOjMzOjE3LjQzMloiLCJpZCI6IjU2ODQ0ZDY1Y2UzMjEyZTUwMWE3ZmNmNyIsImlhdCI6MTQ1MTUxNjU5N30.qpDmsnpMaHZy4QITS5IBPhPieNER7QHKSFWzsvulWC8';
      storeToken(token);
      dispatch(receiveLogin({ user: { username: 'admin', uid: 1 }, token }));
      dispatch(pushPath('/'));
    }, 3000);
  };
};

export const actions = {
  doLogin,
  isAuthenticated
};

// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
export default handleActions({
  [LOGIN_REQUEST]: (state, { payload }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      isFetching: true,
      isAuthenticated: false
    };
  },
  [LOGIN_SUCCESS]: (state, { payload }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      isFetching: false,
      isAuthenticated: true,
      token: payload.token,
      user: payload.user
    };
  },
  [LOGIN_FAILURE]: (state, { payload }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      isFetching: false,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      message: payload
    };
  }
}, initialState);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

// NOTE: here we're making use of the `resolve.root` configuration
// option in webpack, which allows us to specify import paths as if
// they were from the root of the ~/src directory. This makes it
// very easy to navigate to files regardless of how deeply nested
// your current file is.
import CoreLayout from 'layouts/CoreLayout';
import AuthLayout from 'layouts/AuthLayout';

import HomeView from 'views/HomeView';
import LoginView from 'views/auth/LoginView';

import { actions as authActions } from '../redux/modules/auth';

function isAuthenticated (nextState, replaceState) {
  if (authActions.isAuthenticated()) {
    replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/auth/login');
  }
}

export default (<Route>
  <Route path='/' component={CoreLayout} onEnter={isAuthenticated}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
    <Route path='/panel' name='Panel' component={HomeView} />
  </Route>
  <Route path='/auth' component={AuthLayout}>
    <Route path='login' component={LoginView} />
  </Route>
</Route>);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been using this solution with https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit

1. Create AuthenticatedComponent
   https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example/blob/master/src/components/AuthenticatedComponent.js
2. Config router component require authen: https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example/blob/master/src/routes/index.js
3. Check token (page loading): https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example/blob/master/src/index.js